# Laravel 5 controller to list appointments by date range and by label

Tags: php, mvc, controller, laravel

I am starting to get into OOP using PHP and MVC. I just want to know if this code is good practice. Is this how I should be using my controller and model, in its simplest form?

AppointmentsController:

```
public function index()
{
    $appointmentsByLabel        = Appointment::findAppointmentsByLabel('2');
    $appointmentsBetweenDates   = Appointment::findAppointmentsBetweenDates('2016-02-01', '2016-03-31');

    return view('appointments', compact('appointmentsBetweenDates', 'appointmentsByLabel'));
}
```

Model (Appointment):

```
public static function findAppointmentsBetweenDates($start, $end)
{
    $appointments = Appointment::whereBetween('start',array($start,$end))->get();

    return $appointments;
}

public static function findAppointmentsByLabel($value)
{
    $appointments = Appointment::where('label_id', '=', $value)->get();

    return $appointments;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the name of the classes? The model class is named `Appointment`, right? It's a bit confusing, as you are using `Appointment` inside the class, instead of `this`. If you want to, you could also add the `whereBetween` and `where` methods, for a bit more context. But generally, this seems like an alright structure.

Comment: @tim, I've indeed called my model Appointment. I am not using `this` because the method should be static. Or I am missing something :)

Comment: @RonBrouwers oh, sorry, I overlooked the static. Yes, this doesn't work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure looks ok to me (I'm not that familiar with laravel, but this is basically how MVC in a web context generally looks). A couple of minor points:

- you don't really need one-time variables such as `$appointments`, just return directly.
- `findAppointments*` could be renamed to `find*`. It's in the `Appointment` class, so it's expected that it will find an appointment, unless noted otherwise. This also avoids the odd phrasing of `Appointment::findAppointments` and makes it `Appointment::find`.
- be as explicit with your variable names as possible (here, it's not so important, but it's good practice, and for larger methods it does get important). eg `value` could be `label`, or even `labelId`, and `start`/`end` could be `startDate`/`endDate` (it may seem that this is a contradiction with the point above, but it's really not; the variables will be used inside the method, missing the direct context of the method name, while the methods will be called either directly on the class as you are doing, or on a variable, which will be named after the class, giving them direct context).
- You can use `self::` instead of `ClassName::`, even in static methods.